# Using SQL to populate Select values

Tags: php, html

Populate multiple Select options using the same value.

Expanding a bit on this question: [Populating dropdown with query results in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410276/populating-dropdown-with-query-results-in-php)

If I have multiple select items I want populated with the same SQL query, is there a way I can loop through the entire table to populate them all?

I have this:

```
    <td class="tg-0pky"><Select length ="10" name ="30DayEmail" value="'.$row['30DayEmail'].'">';

    $sql = "SELECT Health FROM health LIMIT 3";
        $Health_results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        while($Health_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Health_results)) {
        echo "\t\t".'<option value="'.$Health_row['Health'].'">'.$Health_row['Health'].'</option>'."\n";
      }
```

That works great, but I don't want to have to paste that to all ofthe other 50 some select options I have.

Comment: Are you missing an `echo` on the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the results in a variable so you can echo it in all the places.

```
$options = "";
$sql = "SELECT Health FROM health LIMIT 3";
$Health_results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($Health_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Health_results)) {
    $options .= "\t\t".'<option value="'.$Health_row['Health'].'">'.$Health_row['Health'].'</option>'."\n";
}

echo '<td class="tg-0pky"><Select length ="10" name ="30DayEmail" value="'.$row['30DayEmail'].'">'.$options.'</select></td>';
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks for adding the additional step of how to echo the table class.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead retrieve all of the results from your SQL query into an array (using [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)) and then loop over the result array each time for each select...

```
$sql = "SELECT Health FROM health LIMIT 3";
$Health_results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$health_values = mysqli_fetch_all($Health_results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ( $health_values as $health) {
    echo "\t\t".'<option value="'.$health['Health'].'">'.$health['Health'].'</option>'."\n";
}
```

Alternatively, if each list of options is exactly the same, you could build a string at the start and then just echo this string each time...

```
$sql = "SELECT Health FROM health LIMIT 3";
$options = '';
$Health_results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($Health_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Health_results)) {
    $options.= "\t\t".'<option value="'.$Health_row['Health'].'">'.$Health_row['Health'].'</option>'."\n";
  }
```

Then `$options` can be used each time.